# How to merge the objects having same id and corresponding array objects which are nested inside the object in a array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge the objects having same id and their corresponding array of objects having same value to that corresponding id of the object, which is nested inside the object. For example

```
[{
"id": "1",
"reference": "<p>test 1</p>",
"list": [
  {
    "text": "<p>text a</p>",
  },
  {
    "text": "<p>text b</p>",
  }
]},{
"id": "1",
"reference": "<p>test 1</p>",
"list": [
  {
    "text": "<p>text b</p>",
  }
]},{
"id": "2",
"reference": "<p>test 2</p>",
"list": [
  {
    "text": "<p>test e</p>",
  },
  {
    "text": "<p>text c</p>",
  },
  {
    "text": "<p>text c</p>",
  }
]},{
"id": "2",
"reference": "<p>test 2</p>",
"list": [
  {
    "text": "<p>test e</p>",
  },
  {
    "text": "<p>text c</p>",
  }
]},{
"id": "3",
"reference": "<p>test 3</p>",
"list": [
  {
    "text": "<p>text d</p>",
  }
]}]
```

The expected result is

```
[{
"id": "1",
"reference": "<p>test 1</p>",
"list": [
  {
    "text": "<p>text a</p>",
  },
  {
    "text": "<p>text b</p>",
  }
]},{
"id": "2",
"reference": "<p>test 2</p>",
"list": [
  {
    "text": "<p>text c</p>",
  },
  {
    "text": "<p>test e</p>",
  }
]},{
"id": "3",
"reference": "<p>test 3</p>",
"list": [
  {
    "text": "<p>text d</p>",
  }
]}]
```

I tried the following way, but didnot get the expected result. Dont know where I am going wrong.
Please dont recommend the use of `.reduce()`.

```js
const originalArray = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "reference": "<p>test 1</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>text a</p>",
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>text b</p>",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "reference": "<p>test 1</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>text b</p>",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "reference": "<p>test 2</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>test e</p>",
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>text c</p>",
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>text c</p>",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "reference": "<p>test 2</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>test e</p>",
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>text c</p>",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "reference": "<p>test 3</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>text d</p>",
      }
    ]
  }
];

    var newArray = [];
    var lookupObject = {};
    for (var i in originalArray) {
      lookupObject[originalArray[i]["id"]] = originalArray[i];
    }
    for (i in lookupObject) {
      newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
    }
    console.log(newArray)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested objects for keeping track of seen values.

```js
const
    originalArray = [{ id: "1", reference: "<p>test 1</p>", list: [{ text: "<p>text a</p>" }, { text: "<p>text b</p>" }] }, { id: "1", reference: "<p>test 1</p>", list: [{ text: "<p>text b</p>" }] }, { id: "2", reference: "<p>test 2</p>", list: [{ text: "<p>test e</p>" }, { text: "<p>text c</p>" }, { text: "<p>text c</p>" }] }, { id: "2", reference: "<p>test 2</p>", list: [{ text: "<p>test e</p>" }, { text: "<p>text c</p>" }] }, { id: "3", reference: "<p>test 3</p>", list: [{ text: "<p>text d</p>" }] }],
    newArray = [],
    lookupObject = {};

for (const item of originalArray) {
    if (!lookupObject[item.id]) {
        lookupObject[item.id] = { text: {}, payload: { ...item, list: [] } };
        newArray.push(lookupObject[item.id].payload);
    }
    for (const { text } of item.list) {
        if (!lookupObject[item.id][text]) {
            lookupObject[item.id][text] = true;
            lookupObject[item.id].payload.list.push({ text });
        }
    }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the  `list` items if the object with the `id` is already in `lookupObject`, and then filter out duplicates in each object's list:

```js
const originalArray = [
  { "id": "1", "reference": "<p>test 1</p>", "list": [ { "text": "<p>text a</p>" }, { "text": "<p>text b</p>" } ] },
  { "id": "1", "reference": "<p>test 1</p>", "list": [ { "text": "<p>text b</p>" } ] },
  { "id": "2", "reference": "<p>test 2</p>", "list": [ { "text": "<p>test e</p>" }, { "text": "<p>text c</p>" }, { "text": "<p>text c</p>" } ] },
  { "id": "2", "reference": "<p>test 2</p>", "list": [ { "text": "<p>test e</p>" }, { "text": "<p>text c</p>" } ] },
  { "id": "3", "reference": "<p>test 3</p>", "list": [ { "text": "<p>text d</p>" } ] }
];

var newArray = [];
var lookupObject = {};

for (var i in originalArray) {
  const id = originalArray[i]["id"];
  const itemWithId = lookupObject[id];
  if(itemWithId) {
    itemWithId.list = [ ...itemWithId.list, ...originalArray[i]["list"] ];
  } else {
    lookupObject[id] = originalArray[i];
  }
}
// remove duplicate items in the lists
for (i in lookupObject) {
  const item = lookupObject[i];
  const uniqueItems = new Set();
  item.list = [...item.list].filter(({ text: listItemText }) =>
    !uniqueItems.has(listItemText) && uniqueItems.add(listItemText)
  );
}
for (i in lookupObject) {
  newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
}
    
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: I think the only thing missing is removing the duplicates in the list arrays